# Consume Sharepoint Online REST API from Moodle (PHP)

Tags: 2013

I need to read list items from a sharepoint list, which if I am in sharepoint it works perfectly fine.

However I need from Moodle to read data from a sharepoint list, Moodle and Azure AD are connected already using this plugin:
https://moodle.org/plugins/local_o365

Is this doable? or not possible with JS to get the authentication somehow before I can do the HTTP request?

Comment: Search for PHP PDO SharePoint or something like that... there is a PHP library that connects to Sp

Comment: are you sure it works for SPO and not only for on premises?

Comment: If the answer was helpful could you remove it from the SO unanswered list, by marking it as answered, tnx

Answer (score 1):

### https://github.com/vgrem/phpSPO

**About**

The library provides a Office 365 REST client for PHP applications. It allows to performs CRUD operations against Office 365 resources via an REST/OData based API.

**The list of supported Office 365 REST APIs:**

SharePoint REST API (supported versions: SharePoint 2013, SharePoint 2016, ***SharePoint Online*** and OneDrive for Business)
Outlook REST API
Outlook Contacts REST API
Outlook Calendar REST API
Outlook Mail REST API
OneNote REST API